# Error in Multiple Models When Used in a VIEW

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to get access to multiple models in my view.

I created a `ViewModel` class and its controller and I imported the model to view but I got this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
>       'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LivrinhosMVC.Models.Category]', but this 
>       dictionary requires a model item of type 'LivrinhosMVC.Models.ViewModel'.**

ViewModel Class:

```
public class ViewModel
        {
            public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
            public List<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
        }
```

ViewModel Controller:

```
// GET: ViewModel
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModel mymodel = new ViewModel();
        mymodel.Categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        mymodel.Ads = db.Ads.ToList();
        return View(mymodel);           
    }
```

View:

```
@model LivrinhosMVC.Models.ViewModel
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin:2em 0">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.Label("Categorias")
            <table class="table-condensed">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "../Category/Books", new { id = item.ID }, null)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="display:inline">
            @Html.TextBox("BookTitle", null, new { placeholder = "Título...", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.DropDownList("Cities", "Portugal")
            @Html.ActionLink("Pesquisar", "Books", null, null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Ads)
            {
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.Label(item.Title)
            </div>


            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try eagerly load the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) you want to send to the view.

Such as:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = db.ViewModel
        .Include(c => c.Categories);
        .Include(c => c.Ads);

    return View(model.ToList());
}
```

And make the view Strogly typed as:

```
@model IEnumerable<LivrinhosMVC.Models.ViewModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure based on your example code why you would be getting that error, it seems to have an issue with `@foreach (var item in Model.Categories)`.

What I can see, and recommend though, is to follow through with the view model approach, but do not attach entities into the view model. View models should be simple POCO classes that only expose enough detail for the view to consume, nothing more. The reason for this is to help boost performance (less data read and transmitted) and boost security. (no data sent to the client you don't expect them to see, such as exposed in debugging tools, and ensure that Entities are not sent back to the server with unintentional edits, again through debugging tools, trusted, and attached and committed to the context.)

I would suggest creating a CategorySummaryViewModel and an AdSummaryViewModel containing just the ID and Name to start. Mark all view models as Serializable. Then when you populate your ViewModel:

```
[Serializable]
public class AdsPageViewModel
{
  public List<CategorySummaryViewModel> Categories { get; set; } = new List<CategorySummaryViewModel>();
  public List<AdSummaryViewModel> Ads { get; set; } = new List<AdSummaryViewModel>();
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
  var mymodel = new AdsPageViewModel
  {
    Categories = db.Categories.Select(x=> new CategorySummaryViewModel
    {
      Id = x.Id,
      Name = x.Name // Append other fields if necessary for the view.
    }).ToList(),
    Ads = db.Ads.Select(x => new AdSummaryViewModel
    {
      Id = x.Id,
      Name = x.Name
    }).ToList()
  };
  return View(mymodel);           
}
```

This will seem like more code/effort than simply passing the entities. You can leverage a tool like Automapper to simplify this, and utilize `.ProjectTo<T>` to gain the same benefits as above. These benefits include that by using `.Select()` the EF SQL statement sent to the database, and data coming back from the database only include the fields our view model needs. Less data over the wire = faster, and less memory needed on the app server and client for the request. It also ensures our view can only ever see the fields we want it to see. Someone using F12 in our client can't inspect other FKs and fields that are hidden only because we don't have controls visible on the page. We also ensure that our application does not accept entities back from the client where the enticement will be to attach them to a context and save them. (seems simple, but vulnerable to hackers altering the entity data using those same debugging tools and corrupting the data saved.)

Give that a go with serializable POCO view models to make up the view's data and see if you still get any exception around rendering the child collections. I suspect if there still is an issue there may be a detail from your code that isn't covered by your example here.

Comment: It doesn't work
Error:'IEnumerable<ViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Category' and no extension method 'Category' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<ViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The error is in foreach at Model.Category and Model.Ad

Comment: Then I suspect there is something missing from your example that makes it significantly different from the code you are trying to run. Based on what you are describing the view is expecting a collection of view models, not a single view model. What you've provided in your example above should work just fine.